# How to add transition animation to element in React Native

Tags: react-native

I have an arrow icon, like this:

```
<View style={[styles.icon, dropdownOpen && {transform: [{rotate: '180deg'}] }]}>
   <Icon name="arrow-down" size={20} color="#444"}>
</View>
```

Then I have the state:

```
const [dropdownOpen, setDropdownOpen] = useState(false);
```

This state is driven by another component, and it works fine, but there's no transition, of course.

I know I can use Animated API but I can't wrap my head around how to do it.

I guess I should use `Animated.View` for the `View` but where should I put the `Animated.Value` for example?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using hooks. You can use useReft for an animated value, then in a useEffect you can trigger the animated value like so:

```js
const [dropdownOpen, setDropdownOpen] = useState(false);
  const animatedIconRotation = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;
  useEffect(() => {
    Animated.timing(animatedIconRotation, {
      duration: 100,
      easing: Easing.linear,
      toValue: dropdownOpen ? 180 : 0,
      useNativeDriver: true,
    }).start();
  }, [dropdownOpen]);
```

It will go from 0 degree to 180 when the dropDown open is set to true and rotate back from 180 to 0 when it goes to 0.

Duration being the time it will take to go from the original value to the final value in millisecondes.

useNativeDriver to true essentially make it behave nicely ([more details here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2017/02/14/using-native-driver-for-animated))

easing being the way the value progressively changes, I think in your case linear is what you are after. More options and details [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/easing)

Then in your component something alongside this should do:

```html
<View style={[styles.icon, {transform: [{rotate: `${animatedIconRotation}deg`}] }]}>
  <Icon name="arrow-down" size={20} color="#444"/>
</View>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but tried and didn't work. Tried comenting the useeffect part and leaving only the useref declaration, changing the starting value to 50 for example but it didn't rotate at all, however, console logging it logged 50 si the value is there.

Also tried removing the useRef and just declaring the value and that rotated the view. So the rotation is working but I'm lost

Comment: actually, logging the `animatedIconRotation` logs an object

Comment: I solved it! I had to use interpolate for it to work, so I animated from 0 to 1, and interpolated from '0deg' to '180deg'

Comment: use <Animated.View> instead <View>